# A weird function graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, conic-sections

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wpfmd3l3ev

If you see the graph in the above link, it will appear as if it under a parabola. Could someone explain what part of the function makes it appear like this.

Also,  if you are interested, here are some interesting plots that I got when I played around with the function:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fdyiskame5

Comment: I know it isn't filling the area, I didn't know how else to frame it.

Comment: Perhaps your question is: *Why is the graph always below the parabola?*

Comment: yes thanks for your suggestion